# Finding the limits of triple integral.

Tags: integration

When solving a normal triple integral, we can "downgrade" it to a double integral while integrating over all values of the axis, for example; the volume of

$$A=\Big\{ (x,y,z)~\Big| ~ \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}} \le z \le C-
 \frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}\Big\}$$

We can downgrade the integral to the form of 
$$\int_A dA = \int_{Dz} dxdy\int_{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}}}^{C-
 \frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}}dz$$

This is true because a triple integral is a Reimman's sum and is intuitive, however the region $D_z$ is unclear to me, how do we decide what is it? for any $z$ it is a different values, so shouldn't the integral be inverted?

How do we decide the new integration limits both geometrically and algebraically?

Could this question be extended to any volume of type $(x,y,z), f(x,y) \le z \le g(x,y)$